# DirectX: 'empty sample' compile error (x86) - 1 unresolved error

Tags: c++, directx

I tried to compile Direct 3D sample, called "EmptyProject" - I added to project links: "Include" folder and "Lib/x86" folder with libraries.
But while compiling I've got error:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __vsnwprintf referenced in function "long __stdcall StringVPrintfWorkerW(unsigned short *,unsigned int,unsigned int *,unsigned short const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerW@@YGJPAGIPAIPBGPAD@Z)    EmptyProject    C:\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Direct3D\EmptyProject - Copy\dxerr.lib(dxerrw.obj) 1
```

[image]

How it can be fixed?

Thank you

Comment: Have you added lib files to the input section in project configuration?

Comment: @AdrienGivry Yes, a added "Lib" folder and "Include" folder  in Project Properties

Comment: Yes you added the folders, but did you specified the name of every .lib in : Project --> Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies (Also verify you are editing the right Configuration and Platform in property editor)